# How to speed up the execution of jquery in the body of an ASP page

Tags: jquery, html, asp-classic

I am running some jquery in the body of an asp file. Immediately after it is the drop down menu that it effects. 
The script works fine, the issue is it takes a while to load the script in firefox.

How can I speed this up without moving it higher up in the body or header.

Please note: The link provided is the live website, I am aware that it is firing an object error back because I have
a old version of jQuery. (On our internal website the jquery is the latest version)

Link:http://www.casa.gov.au/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:PWA::pc=PC_91330

The code is below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

              $(document).on("change","select#state",function(e){
                             $("form#state").submit();
                               });

     });
</script>

  <form id="state" action="avsafety.asp" method="get">

     <p>State:<br/>
      <select id="state" name="state">
        <option label="ACT" value="ACT" <%if request.querystring("state") = "ACT" then response.write("selected") %>>ACT</option>
        <option label="NSW" value="NSW" <%if request.querystring("state") = "NSW" then response.write("selected") %>>NSW</option>
        <option label="NT" value="NT"   <%if request.querystring("state") = "NT" then response.write("selected") %>>NT</option>
        <option label="QLD" value="QLD" <%if request.querystring("state") = "QLD" then response.write("selected") %>>QLD</option>
        <option label="VIC" value="VIC" <%if request.querystring("state") = "VIC" then response.write("selected") %>>VIC</option>
        <option label="SA" value="SA"   <%if request.querystring("state") = "SA" then response.write("selected") %>>SA</option>
        <option label="TAS" value="TAS" <%if request.querystring("state") = "TAS" then response.write("selected") %>>TAS</option>
        <option label="WA" value="WA"   <%if request.querystring("state") = "WA" then response.write("selected") %>>WA</option>
      </select>
      <noscript><input type="submit" value="Search" /></noscript>
    </p>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `on` for the entire document. Essentially waiting for events to bubble all the way up to the highest level. Monitor the element directly.

```
$("select#state").on("change",function(e){
    $("form#state").submit();
});
```

In terms of larger performance gains I would look less at this individual bit of javascript and more at your site as a whole. Why is it loading slow? You could enable compression, leverage a CDN.

Also, seems strange that FF would be slow. Usually (always?) it is IE that ends up being slow. You might want to try another computer and see how fast it is. There may be extensions in FF that are causing problems.

You can also leverage Chrome developer tools. Inspect to see what portions or your site are causing the biggest performance hit. Because `$(document).ready()` is waiting for the DOM to load, a single element may be the cause of the performance problem.

Comment: @sephiith, you may also want to profile your loads with the Firebug addon (net panel). I'm seeing a lot of waiting for items to be received, especially in the download of your javascript files. You can also use the YSlow addon to Firebug to get a report and suggestions on speeding things up. Currently your overall score is C (Example: Your site gets an F on the test for usage of GZip).